# Controlling a style based on a DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, dependency-properties

So, I'm making a WPF Application using the M-V-VM design pattern and having some trouble getting my Bindings to work properly.

I have a custom ToggleButton, and the way I want it to work is this:

1. When the IsChecked property of the control is set to true, then it should query a second boolean (contained within the ViewModel) is also true.
2. If it is, set the background colour to one colour, if not then set it to a different colour.
3. If IsChecked is false, use the standard colour.

In the xaml, I have this style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomisableToggleButton}" x:Key="ValidatedTButton">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsValid}" Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Turquoise" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsValid}" Value="False" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCoral" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

(CustomisableToggleButton is a catch all style that applies to ToggleButtons - AFAIK this should override the triggers that are inherent in that - correct me if I'm wrong)

In the Control Class:

```
public class ValidatedToggleButton : ToggleButton
{
    public ValidatedToggleButton()
        : base() { }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsValidProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsValid", typeof(bool), typeof(ValidatedToggleButton));

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsValidProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsValidProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And the actual implementation of the control is:

```
<Window
<!--standard window properties-->
    xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:MVVM.CustomControls"> // namespace where 'ValidatedToggleButton' resides

<!--other XAML code-->

    <cc:ValidatedToggleButton 
        IsValid="{Binding Boolean1}" 
        Content="ToggleButton1" 
        IsChecked="{Binding ToggleButton1Checked}" 
        Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource ValidatedTButton}" />

</Window>
```

Now, the problem is, it never checks the 'Boolean1' value apart from once at startup (verified using breakpoints). How can I make it check that value every time the control is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [Kent's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835285/controlling-a-style-based-on-a-dependencyproperty/7835914#7835914) of fixing your XAML bindings, verify that the `PropertyChanged` event is getting raised when `Boolean1` is changing.

You can do this by inserting a breakpoint in the `get` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True" />
```

This is looking for a property called `IsChecked` on your view model (your data context). Are you sure you don't want this:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />
```

Comment: I did miss that, but unfortunately no cigar. Anyway, 'IsChecked' seems to be working fine, it's just 'IsValid' that seems to be causing the issues.

Comment: Taking this answer and applying it to 'IsValid' produced an interesting result - now the ToggleButton is always showing up as the invalid colour rather than the valid one... strange.

Comment: @KristianFenn Do the same thing with the `IsValid` property. Right now it looks like you are checking the value of `ValidatingToggleButton.DataContext.IsValid`, which I am guessing does not exist. By setting the `RelativeSource` to `Self`, you're changing it to look at `ValidatingToggleButton.IsValid`

Comment: @KristianFenn Sorry, I didn't see that. You've verified that the `Boolean1` property on your DataContext is getting set to true and raises the PropertyChanged event?

Comment: @Rachel The property 'Boolean1' isn't following the normal public property to expose private member pattern - it returns the result of a comparison. As a result, there's no set{} part to the property as there's no private member to set.

Comment: Added NotifyPropertyChanged() events to everywhere that the 'Boolean1' comparison parameters get changed. Still no cigar.

Comment: @KristianFenn Can you set a breakpoint in the `get` method for `Boolean1` and verify that it's getting called when you manually raise the PropertyChanged events?

Comment: @Rachel This would appear to be a problem with the comparison. However, some NotifyPropertyChanged() calls were missing, which solves the issue of 'Boolean1' never being checked after initialise. I'd accept your answer, but unfortunately it is a comment.

Comment: @KristianFenn I posted it as an answer, but I'd still recommend giving Kent a +1 for posting the solution to your original question :)